# Very slow syncronization

Tags: node

My tezos mainnet node very slow syncs, most messages in console:

```
8/6/2019 5:56:49 PMAug  6 14:56:49 - validator.peer_40: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idtkWrLiuRp3
8/6/2019 5:56:49 PMAug  6 14:56:49 - validator.peer_40: Worker terminated [NetXdQprcVkpa:idtkWrLiuRp3]
8/6/2019 5:56:50 PMAug  6 14:56:50 - validator.peer_41: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idsJFAtMfLo2
8/6/2019 5:56:50 PMAug  6 14:56:50 - validator.peer_41: Worker terminated [NetXdQprcVkpa:idsJFAtMfLo2]
8/6/2019 5:56:51 PMAug  6 14:56:51 - validator.peer_42: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idsnSXVnU2QL
8/6/2019 5:56:51 PMAug  6 14:56:51 - validator.peer_42: Worker terminated [NetXdQprcVkpa:idsnSXVnU2QL]
8/6/2019 5:56:52 PMAug  6 14:56:52 - validator.peer_43: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idqr69FRrU2Y
8/6/2019 5:56:54 PMAug  6 14:56:54 - validator.peer_44: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idsgpdGFfii1
8/6/2019 5:56:57 PMAug  6 14:56:57 - validator.peer_45: Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa:idriVMW2AEqA
8/6/2019 5:56:57 PMAug  6 14:56:57 - validator.peer_45: Worker terminated [NetXdQprcVkpa:idriVMW2AEqA]
```

Peer_N may up to 2000, but synced also very slow. (~1 day = 5000 levels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving (or bootstrapping) a full chain (from the genesis to the current head) can be a very long process. Indeed, many parameters influences this process, such as the length of the chain, the network speed and connectivity, the disk I/O rate, the computing power …

In order to speed up the setup of a node, you should consider using storage snapshots ([technical blog article](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html)) to speedup this process. A comprehensive guide to use snapshots can be found here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/snapshots.html

Regarding the worker started/terminated sequence (which should not influence the bootstrap speed that much), a fix was merged ([MR 1195](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/merge_requests/1195)) and will be available in mainnet soon.